# Attach listener to MemoryCache which can remove expired items

Tags: c#, memorycache

I am using `MemoryCache` in one of my project to cache some keys and value. I have attached a listener on my `MemoryCache` that whenever it is expiring any items then that listener should get called so that I can remove those keys from `CacheKeys` `HashSet` as well. Basically I want to be consistent with what I have in `CacheKeys` and `MemoryCache`.

I read about `MemoryCache` and looks like I can use `RegisterPostEvictionCallback` as shown below:

```
private static readonly HashSet<string> CacheKeys = new HashSet<string>();

private bool CacheEntries<T>(MemoryCache memoryCache, string cacheKey, T value, Configuration config, Action<MemoryCacheEntryOptions> otherOptions = null)
{
    int minutes = randomGenerator.Next(config.LowTime, config.HighTime);

    MemoryCacheEntryOptions options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
    {
        Size = config.Size,
        Priority = config.Priority,
        AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes)
    };
    // attaching listener
    options.RegisterPostEvictionCallback(callback: EvictionCallback, state: this);
    
    if (otherOptions != null) otherOptions(options);

    CacheKeys.Add(cacheKey);
    memoryCache.Set<T>(cacheKey, value, options);

    return true;
}

private void EvictionCallback(object key, object value, EvictionReason reason, object state)
{
    CacheKeys.Remove(key);
    var message = $"Entry was evicted. Reason: {reason}.";
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

It looks like there is some issue where items doesn't expire automatically as per this this [thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/248).

So to avoid the issue mentioned in that thread. Do I need to remove `AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow` and use `CancellationTokenSource` here?

If yes, how should I go ahead and make the change since I don't want to change the current functionality that I have already in my original code so if I remove `AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow` and use `CancellationTokenSource` here will it behave differently than what my original code is doing?

Comment: Aren't you worried about race conditions e.g. the cache and CacheKeys to get out of sync?

Comment: To keep them in sync that's what I am trying to do by removing entries from `CacheKeys` data structure whenever items expired from `MemoryCache`. Unless I missed something else here. This is the whole purpose of this task to keep them in sync always whenever possible.

Comment: Yes, but, there is a moment time between when the key is added to CacheKeys and when the item is added to the cache; and a moment between when the item is removed from the cache and when the callback removes the key from CacheKeys. During those moments, client code could think the item was in the cache (because the key is in CacheKeys) but it actually is not in the cache.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point and I am mostly ok with that since the task that I am trying to do is not gonna be impacted because of that small delay.

Comment: Every time I've seen a cache implementation, you check if something is in the cache by trying to get it from the cache. If the cache returns null, then it's not in the cache and you need to get it from the source.

Comment: To answer what I think is your original question - the reason the item is being removed (be it an expiration expiring or a cancellationtoken firing) shouldn't matter, the eviction callback should still be called regardless. The reason might be different, but you're only using that for logging in your example code.